# How to alert the starting and ending dates of previous week

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to Alert all the starting and ending dates of previous weeks.

```
var weekCount = 0;
$(".week-prev").live('click', function() {
    var weekdate = new Date();
    var fromweek = weekdate.setTime(weekdate.getTime() - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    var toweek = weekdate.setTime(weekdate.getTime() - (weekdate.getDay() ? weekdate.getDay() : 7) + weekCount * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    var prevweekstart = new Date(fromweek);
    var prevweekends = new Date(toweek);
    prevweekstart = prevweekstart.toLocaleString(),
            prevweekends = prevweekends.toLocaleString(),
            between = [];
    alert(prevweekstart);
    alert(prevweekends);
});
```

Comment: hellow samitha,at first click i got  4/26/2014 and 4/19/2014. But i needs to alert starting and ending dates of all previous weeks on each click event

Comment: Like [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/9bwdA/3/) ?

Comment: yes Batu its look like same but needs some change. Like previous Sunday Saturday order.

Comment: hellow Batu Zet there is some error

Comment: some error there. not getting always sun,sat

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) for all date manipulations in Javascript

```
moment().startOf('week');    // set to the first day of this week, 12:00 am
moment().startOf('isoWeek'); // set to the first day of this week according to ISO 8601, 12:00 am
moment().endOf('week');    // set to the last day of this week, 12:00 am
moment().endOf('isoWeek'); // set to the last day of this week according to ISO 8601, 12:00 am
```

As of version 2.1.0, moment#startOf('week') uses the locale aware week start day.

For your example with the previous week you would use:

```
moment().subtract('weeks', 1).startOf('week');
```